# Page_Load executes twice

Tags: asp.net

This issue has to with my page loading twice on a post back. I'm not up to par with the page life cycle in asp.net hence my post.

Short searching revealed that AutoEventWireup is a player in this which presently is not referenced in my Page directive. Stepping through the code the Page_Load executes two times, first time from the OnInint/InitializeComponent where the following was auto generated: `this.Load += new System.EventHandler(this.Page_Load);`. The main issue is this: I have class level variable `Int32 totalDuration = 0;` that is populated in the gridView RowDataBound event by adding up the values of a cell called "Duration". For example the grid view contains two rows where in the first row the cell contains a value of 35 (minutes) and the second row contains 25. The purpose is to add up all the minutes from each row. Here is the simplified method:

```
protected void gv_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        DataRowView drv = (DataRowView)e.Row.DataItem;

        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            totalDuration = totalDuration + Convert.ToInt32(drv["Duration"]);
        }

        lblMinutes.Text = totalDuration.ToString("#,##0");
    }
```

Because the Page_Load executes twice the value of totalDuration is doubled, which is obviously incorrect. As a fix I commented out the  `this.Load += new System.EventHandler(this.Page_Load);` in the InitializeComponents method. Site and page seem to work but I am not certain if this really a solution for the underlying issue.

I am open to your suggestions and I would welcome some explanation about the whole InitilalizeComponent or the Autowireup stuff, etc.

Thank you,
Risho

EDIT: The Page_Load looks like this:

```
private void Page_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            /code removed/

            bindGrid(site, metric, month, year);
        }
    }

private void bindGrid(string site, string metric, int month, int year)
    {
        /code removed/
        gv.DataSource = dvSearch;
        gv.DataBind();
    }
```

Comment: Do other methods execute twice, like Page_Init or Page_Unload? If so, I would suspect your event 'extra' event registration is the culprit. Why are you doing that anyway?

Comment: @Jeffery Khan: Postbacks do occur, see my edot of the original post.

Comment: @n8wrl: Only page load fire twice. Why am I doing what? You mean adding up the values in the cells? I just inherited this app with this issue and was ask to fix it. Some one else wrote it this way.

Comment: I've come accros posts which suggest that empty src property string of image tags, i.e. scr="" would cause postbacks. The menu in this app is done with Infradistics UltraWebNavigator located in the master and all the HoverImageUrl were set to just an empty string with two double quotes. I've since added a value but that did nothing.

Comment: I keep finding more on this such as the AutoEventWireup setting. I added this to my page directive setting it to false and my issue went away. Does this mean that if this is set to false I don't need the this.Load += new System.EventHandler(this.Page_Load); in the OnInint/InitializeComponent methods?